# Solve $636^{369}\equiv x\pmod{126}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Solve
>
> $$636^{369}\equiv x\pmod{126}$$

**My attempt:**

$$126=2\times 3^2 \times 7$$

$$\varphi(126)=\varphi(2)\times \varphi(3^2)\times \varphi(7)=36$$

$$\color{gray}{636=6\pmod{126}}$$

$$6^{369}\equiv x \pmod{126}$$

$$2^{369}3^{369}\equiv x \pmod{126}$$

I am stuck here

Comment: Hint: $6^6=370\cdot 126+6^2$

Comment: You can't just simply apply Euler's Th here because 636 and 126 are not coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little guess work, combined with [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), can save efforts.
We look at each modulus $2,7,9$ respectively.
Clearly $636$ is even.
Also $636^{369}\equiv6^{369}\pmod9.$ Since $6^2\equiv0\pmod9,$ we find $6^{369}\equiv0\pmod9.$
And $636\equiv-1\pmod7,$ so $636^{369}\equiv(-1)^{369}\equiv6\pmod7.$
Now apply Chinese remainder theorem: Since $27\equiv0\pmod9$ and $27\equiv6\pmod7,$ we find that $27\pmod{63}$ is the unique number modulo $63$ satisfying the two congruence conditions. Finally, to find $k\pmod{126}$ even such that $\begin{cases}k\equiv0\pmod2\\k\equiv27\pmod{63}\end{cases}$ we simply take $k\equiv27+63=90\pmod{126}.$ Therefore we conclude that $636^{369}\equiv90\pmod{126}.$
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

$636 \equiv 06 \equiv 6 $ (mod 7)

$\varphi(7)=6$

$369 \equiv 09 \equiv 3$ (mod 6)

So

$636^{369}\equiv 6^3 \equiv 36 \times 6 \equiv 6$ (mod 7)

(Note that $gcd(636,7)=1$)

Also, $636\equiv06 \equiv 6$ (mod 9)
and $6\times6=36\equiv 0$ (mod 9)

So

$636^n\equiv 0$ (mod 9) for $n>1$

Therefore, we have $636^{369}=6+7k\equiv 0$ (mod 18)

Hence $k \equiv-\frac{6}{7}\equiv-\frac{42}{7}\equiv-6\equiv12$ (mod 18)

So, finally, $636^{369} =6+7(12+18k')\equiv6+84\equiv90$ (mod 126)

Answer (score 1):

I would exploit the factorization of $126$ already given and solve the equation separately modulo $2$, modulo $3^2=9$, and modulo $7$.  Then apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

It is easy to see that $x$ will have $0$ residue modulo $2$ and modulo $9$.  Only modulo $7$ requires any further work.  The base $636$ has residue $6\equiv-1$ modulo $7$.  The Euler totient function of $7$ is $6$ and the exponent $369$ has residue $3$ modulo $6$.  So $x\equiv(-1)^3\equiv-1$ modulo $7$.

The Chinese Remainder theorem tells us that there will be one residue moodulo $2*9*7=126$ that is divisible by $2*9$ and one less than a multpile of $7$.  This value can be found easily by trial, thus $x\equiv90$ modulo $126$.

Comment: We don't have to know about $\varphi(7):$ as $369$ is odd, it follows that $(-1)^{369}=-1.$

Comment: @awllower Further we don't need CRT - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By $ \ ab\bmod ac\, =\, a\,(b\bmod c)\,$ [[mod Distributive Law]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242)

$\!\underbrace{6^{\large 369}}_{\large 6\ \equiv\ 636}\!\!\bmod 126 = 18\underbrace{(2\cdot 6^{\large 367}\bmod{7}}_{\large 2(-1)^{\large 637}\equiv\ -2\ \equiv\ \color{#c00}5 })  = 18(\color{#c00}5) = 90$